# fullcalendar.js slot highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to fetch the selected slot of a fullcalendar instance and to access it via jQuery after a dayClick event.

```
dayClick:
function(date, jsEvent, view)
        {
                var now = Date.now();                       
                var eventDate = Date.parse(date);
                if(now < eventDate)
                        {
                                selectedSlots.push(eventDate);
                        }
                else
                        {
                                $('#alert_past_event').modal('show');
                        }
        }
```

the correct slot is selected when clicking on it, but how can i access the slot? since it is a "dayClick" event, $(this) will always point to the whole day...

I tried "eventClick" but actually it's only working on events that have already been inserted into the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay while waiting for the 90 minutes questioning delay i figured out a solution for this:

instead of actually accessing the cell i render a new event on that cell:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    {
        title:'',
        color:'007A00',
        start:date,
        end:date_end,
        editable:false,
    });
```

so here's the full "dayClick":

```
    dayClick:
    function(date, jsEvent, view)
        {
            var now = Date.now();
            var eventDate = Date.parse(date);
            if(now < eventDate)
                {
                    selectedSlots.push(eventDate);
                    date_end = date.clone();
                    date_end.add('30','m');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                      {
                          title:'',
                          color:'007A00',
                          start:date,
                          end:date_end,
                          editable:false,
                      });
                }
           else
                {
                     $('#alert_past_event').modal('show');
                }
        }
```